# Load javascripts on JQM data-role='page' onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any way I can run javascripts on JQM 'pages' loads? I have a graph that is supposed to appear in a single page of my JQM page, but if I load it on document.ready it only shows if I refresh that particular JQM 'page'. If I refresh on any other 'page' my graph won't load. Is there like a `onload("#myDiv")` function of some sort that could fix this? The only other solution I have made is to make a button that the user can click to load the graph, but it seems unecessary, should be able to load it automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#wordcloud').bind('pageinit', function() {
    alert("works!");
    });
})
```

Is the code above somewhat close? I do not get an alert though.

Also tried this code both in the div, in the head (inside and outside) `document(ready)`

```
$('#wordcloud').live('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    alert(2);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the [doc](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html), if you want to do something on jQueryMobile page loads, you'd have to use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`.

> pageinit
>
> Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs. We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation system.

Comment: Given the doc, I'd say yes ( example is  `$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});`. But in your example, you have to remove the `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    alert(2);
     drawChart([[["data1",6],["data2",5],["data3",2]]]);    
   } has no method 'split' is from my log, both in and outside the document ready.

Comment: .live instead of .delegate gives no errors, but also no results.

Comment: Kinda hard to debug without the code/markup, could you try to set up a fiddle with your code? ( http://jsfiddle.net/ )

Comment: Yeh, tried that. Just that I needed a tonne of javascript files. I'll make a simplified one, just need a few moments ^^

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SBLgZ/ More or less the essence of it. It's all in jQuery Mobile so it's a pain to have it look somewhat similar to what it does for me :P

Comment: Even when using the built in jQueryMobile of jsfiddle (framework choice on the left)? I never used jsFiddle for jQueryMobile though :p
EDIT: managed to get something that shows an alert when clicking on the link: http://jsfiddle.net/SBLgZ/1/

Comment: I still can't find it in that list :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14129/discussion-between-py-and-tom)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the graph every time the user navigates to the `graphpage`; you  should bind the refresh logic in `pagebeforeshow` handler for the `graphpage`.

Refer to `Page change events` section in the [JQM Events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) documentation.

Comment: Cheers, will look into this. It's great to get some keywords to search for :) Really didn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

use this, to trigger an event every time a #page loads in Jquery mobile

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#dashboard",function(){

   alert("pagebeforeshow event fired - pagetwo is about to be shown");
});
```